# Why would @ngrx/effects use nested observables

Tags: javascript, observable, angular5, ngrx-effects

I was looking into the @ngrx/effects library and they have some example code

```
@Effect() login$ = this.actions$
      // Listen for the 'LOGIN' action
      .ofType('LOGIN')
      // Map the payload into JSON to use as the request body
      .map(action => JSON.stringify(action.payload))
      .switchMap(payload => this.http.post('/auth', payload)
        // If successful, dispatch success action with result
        .map(res => ({ type: 'LOGIN_SUCCESS', payload: res.json() }))
        // If request fails, dispatch failed action
        .catch(() => Observable.of({ type: 'LOGIN_FAILED' }))
      );
```

My question is in the `switchMap` call where the author chose to work off of that observable.

Why wouldn't they choose to take advantage of the "flattening" of `switchMap` and do something like:

```
@Effect() login$ = this.actions$
      // Listen for the 'LOGIN' action
      .ofType('LOGIN')
      // Map the payload into JSON to use as the request body
      .map(action => JSON.stringify(action.payload))
      .switchMap(payload => this.http.post('/auth', payload))
        // If successful, dispatch success action with result
      .map(res => ({ type: 'LOGIN_SUCCESS', payload: res.json() }))
        // If request fails, dispatch failed action
      .catch(() => Observable.of({ type: 'LOGIN_FAILED' }))
      );
```

Notice how in this refactoring `switchMap` just returns the observable from `this.http.post()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

map in both cases yeild the same results, however catch in case 1 will catch errors of only http.post and case 2 will handle errors in any of the observables.